# How do I install a kernel driver so that it is not loaded at all times?

Tags: drivers, grub2, kernel

I would like to install a [kernel driver](https://github.com/slavrn/gm12u320) that is under development and I'm afraid that it could affect the stability of my system. So I would like this driver to only be loaded at certain times (when I want to help debug it). How can I do it?

I expect to be able to do this with a GRUB option, but if this is achievable some other way (e.g. install it for a certain user), that's ok too.

My goal is to keep the experimental driver from affecting stability of the system. It would be nice to know how to remove the driver altogether, too, if I mix something up in the installation process, or if I experience bugs and want to revert a system to a working state. I recently had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch because my laptop kept shutting down at random, until it didn't boot. While it could be some hardware issue, I can't rule out a possiblilty that it was caused by a faulty kernel module. If I start experiencing troubles again, I want to be able to make sure whether it is a consequence of new driver or not.

My system is Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit on [ThinkPad X200](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/detail.page?LegacyDocID=MIGR-73156)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the driver [as a kernel module](http://tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html), [blacklist](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules#Blacklisting_Modules) it by adding

```
blacklist your-module
```

to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` if you don't want to use it.